# Why infinity has minus sign in notation $(-\infty,b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, notation

Why is the convention $(-\infty,b)$ used to represent the interval set of all the real numbers $x$ which are less than $b$? We could write infinity without the minus sign. Why is the minus sign specifically used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the extended real number system, there are the real numbers and two other elements, $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, with the property that for every real number $x$ we have $-\infty<x<+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Because the real numbers are ordered. $-\infty$ is the "smallest" point and $+\infty$ is the "largest" point. We sometimes use $\infty$ for the latter, like we use $2$ instead of $+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the extended real numbers $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty , -\infty \}$ the convention is that $x< \infty $ for $x\in \mathbb R$. Now, the notation $(a,c)$ stands for the set $\{x\in \mathbb R \mid a<x<c\}$. So, the meaning of $(\infty , b)$ would be $\{x\in \mathbb R \mid \infty <x<b\}$, which would thus be the empty set. On the other hand, $(-\infty ,b)$ is the set $\{x\in \mathbb R \mid -\infty <x<b\}$, and since for all $x\in \mathbb R$, $-\infty < x$, it follows that $(-\infty ,b)=\{x\in \mathbb R \mid x<b\}$.

Comment: what does this mean R∪{∞,−∞}? Does this sign ∪ show union here?

Comment: @SamamaFahim Yes.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics *notations* are first introduced for special cases and then, if need be, are extended to cover more general cases in natural ways fulfilling the following criteria:

- Conformity with special, familiar cases
- Being unambiguous.

In the ordered set $(\mathbb{R}, < )$ the following notation is introduced t represent *bounded* sets:$$(a,b) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x < b \} .$$

However, there are two interesting types of sets, namely, *unbounded above* and *unbounded below* sets, which cannot be represented in the original notation above, so we need to extend this notation. Regarding the criteria mentioned earlier, we can extend the notation by introducing the **symbols** $+ \infty = \infty$ and $- \infty$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
(a, \infty ) & = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x \}\\
(- \infty , b) & = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < b \} .
\end{align*}

> We could write infinity without the minus sign.

Yes. We could introduce *only* the symbol $\infty$ and the following notation for unbounded below sets:$$(\infty , b) = \{ x \in\mathbb{R} \mid x < b \} .$$

But this definition would fail to fulfill the second criterion, that is, "being unambiguous". Why? There are two different systems: (i) the *affinely* extended real number $\bar{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty , \infty \}$ and (ii) the *projectively* extended real number $\hat{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$. The former is like an infinite line with two *endpoints* while the latter is like an infinite line with its *endpoints* glued together. This new notation might lead someone to mistake the system in question, that is, $(\mathbb{R}, < )$ for the projectively extended real number. Hence this new notation is not appropriate.

#### Addendum

It should be noted that the context of the question is the real number system, **not** the extended real number system. So regarding $\pm \infty$ as "elements" (or "points") of the system is inappropriate. Also, we **cannot** say "$(\infty , b)$ would be the empty set" because $(\infty , b)$ is **undefinable** and **meaningless** while the empty set is a **defined** entity in mathematics, so comparing them would be inappropriate, even in hypothetical situations.